# I want make a text box area that automatically cuts a long paragraph

Tags: c#, winforms

text box area that automatically cuts a long paragraph text into 30 characters sentences
i am trying run this code but occurs exception [exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException']

```
private void txtCutParagraph_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int limitNum = 30;
    string sentence = txtCutParagraph.Text;
    string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');
    string line = "";

    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        if ((line + word).Length > limitNum)
        {
            newLine += line + "\r\n";
            line = "";
        }

        line += word + " ";
    }

    if (line.Length > 0)
        newLine += line + "\r\n";

    txtCutParagraph.Text = newLine;
}
```

Comment: Where does it break? and where is the newLine variable declared? I guess declared outside, but in that case you need to clear it at the beginning of your routine.

Comment: when run and type first char myform freezing

Comment: sorry newLine declared outside  string newLine = "";

Comment: Do not use TextCHanged() event here! When user is typing in, for each key press you are doing a server call!! Do it with a simple JavaScript. Later, validate again at server side, when form is submitted.

Comment: i need 30 characters in one sentences and take new line automatically

Comment: must not to cut any word in the middle and to cut before or after the word depending on the smaller value.. but not working when run and type one char form is freezing

Comment: Are you working with Widows Form Application? or ASP.NET WebForms?

Comment: Widows Form Application

Comment: And the problem is to prevent the form from freezing?

Comment: im not sure why yours is freezing. i found another problem. your text gets inverted when you start typing.

Comment: i do not know why form freezing and why my code not run ? :(

Comment: create a new form (just for a test). create only one rich text box with this event. run your form and see the results. (do not add anything else so you make sure problem is not here.)

Comment: @AsmaaMohamed , I added a solution to prevent it from freezing! 
Please don't forget to mark it as Answer if it solved your problem!

Comment: You want is to summaries in 30 words o just truncate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called `Word wrapping`. `TextBox` class has Wordwrap option by default. unfortunately you cant limit number of characters per line.

You have to write an algorithm instead. I have noticed that your algorithm does not work correctly. so i decided to write one my self (as it was a good practice!). It is hard to handle all situations that can happen inside text formatting. I tried my best anyway you have to write one your self if you are not satisfied with results.

Before using this algorithm you have to disable Wordwrap feature of Textbox. So they will not Interfere each other. In InitializeComponent inside Form Designer add this line.

```
this.textBox1.WordWrap = false;
```

Now use this algorithm to do it for you! Note that `textbox1` is a multi line text box.

```
private StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
private bool _isInsideTextChanged = false;

private const int MaximumChars = 30; // Maximum characters

private StringBuilder WrapText(StringBuilder text, ref int position)
{
    StringBuilder newStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(text.ToString());

    int charsPerLine = 0;
    int lastSpace = -1; // index of last space per line

    for (int i = 0; i < newStringBuilder.Length; i++)
    {
        if (newStringBuilder[i] == ' ')
        {
            if (newStringBuilder.Length > i + 2 && newStringBuilder.ToString(i + 1, 2) == "\r\n")
            {
                if (newStringBuilder.Length > i + 3)
                {
                    int next = newStringBuilder.ToString().IndexOf(' ', i + 3);

                    if (next != -1 && charsPerLine + next - i <= MaximumChars || charsPerLine + newStringBuilder.Length - i - 2 <= MaximumChars)
                    {
                        newStringBuilder.Remove(i + 1, 2);
                        if (i <= textBox1.SelectionStart)
                        {
                            position -= 2;
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            if (newStringBuilder.Length > i + 1 && newStringBuilder[i + 1] != ' ')
            {
                lastSpace = i;
            }
        }
        if (newStringBuilder[i] == '\n' || newStringBuilder[i] == '\r')
        {
            lastSpace = -1;
            charsPerLine = 0;
        }
        if (++charsPerLine > MaximumChars && lastSpace != -1)
        {
            newStringBuilder.Insert(lastSpace + 1, "\r\n");

            if (lastSpace <= textBox1.SelectionStart)
            {
                position += 2;
            }

            charsPerLine = i - lastSpace;
            lastSpace = -1;
            i++;
        }
    }

    return newStringBuilder;
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_isInsideTextChanged) return;
    _isInsideTextChanged = true;

    stringBuilder.Clear();
    stringBuilder.Append(textBox1.Text);

    int position = textBox1.SelectionStart;
    string newText = WrapText(stringBuilder, ref position).ToString();
    textBox1.Text = newText;
    textBox1.SelectionStart = position;
    _isInsideTextChanged = false;
}
```

Here is the test that shows the results.

[image]

How this wroks?

This algorithm will count the number of characters from last line break index (default value is 0) up to last space character index per line.(default value is -1 means no space in that line). Then it will put line break after last space if the number of characters on that line is more than 30. How ever this algorithm test other things too to better handle text formatting.

This is done every time a textbox value is changed. `StringBuilder` is used instead of `string` to increase performance.

To prevent stack overflow exception as described by @KhaksarWeqar I used a boolean value `_isInsideTextChanged` with `TextChanged` event:

```
private bool _isInsideTextChanged = false;
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_isInsideTextChanged) return; // return if was inside TextChanged.
    _isInsideTextChanged = true; // inside TextChanged

    // Do stuff...

    _isInsideTextChanged = false; // outside TextChanged
}
```

There is also a better way explained on wiki. you can create your own even better!. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap

Answer (score 3):

If the form is freezing is because that `txtCutParagraph_TextChanged` event is firing infinitely, because you are changing the text of `textbox` at the end of the event: `txtCutParagraph.Text = newLine;`, so it means that change text in the textbox, and the event will fire again and again.

To prevent this form from freezing please move your code to another event of textbox, named `KeyPress` as:

```
private void txtCutParagraph_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    int limitNum = 30;
    string sentence = txtCutParagraph.Text;
    string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');
    string line = "";

foreach (string word in words)
{
    if ((line + word).Length > limitNum)
    {
        newLine += line + "\r\n";
        line = "";
    }

    line += word + " ";
}

    if (line.Length > 0)
         newLine += line + "\r\n";

    txtCutParagraph.Text = newLine;
}
```

Comment: interesting, that make sense but in my computer i haven't got this problem. my computer is genius!.

Comment: richtextbox does not fire TextChanged when text is changed inside TextChanged method. i guess there is something like `bool isFired` inside that event that prevents this. however a multi line text box have this problem, and another problem is that text is being inverted.

Comment: Thank you .. it is solve form freezing but also my algorithm do not work correctly